# Vue Prop default() function returns the Object as a String instead of an Object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that defines a prop "actionOptions" of type Object. Also, this prop defines a `default()` function that returns an object with default values.

```js
 actionOptions: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        columnLabel: 'Actions',
      }),
    },
```

Inside `mounted()` I try to print this prop: `console.log(this.actionProps)` the result in the Dev Tools is:

```js
{
  columnLabel: 'Actions',
}
```

With a warning of:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "actionOptions". Expected Object, got String with value "{
  columnLabel: 'Actions',
}"
```

For some reason, Vue is returning the default function results as a string rather than executing it.

I am using vue v^2.6.11. I tried an example on CodeSandbox.io and it works fine there.

Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the code where you are calling this component in the parent, but this error is most likely happening there. I assume currently, your code in the parent looks like this:

```
<ChildComponent action-options="{columnLabel: 'Actions'}" />
```

This means that the prop is being passed as a *string*. If you want to send it as an *object* you should change it to:

```
<ChildComponent :action-options="{columnLabel: 'Actions'}" />
```

This way Vue knows it's a JavaScript object and not a string. [Read More](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Object)

If this doesn't solve the problem, please share the other parts of your both components.

Comment: The component has many other details irrelevant to this problem. Currently, I am using this component inside the Storybook. I know this is something trivial and weird to happen. I've always made use of Props and Defaults. 

I totally understand your point about binding to a string or object. In this case, I am not even passing `action-options` from inside the Storybook story. Therefore, the defaults should take effect, but it's not.

Comment: Even when I print `this.$props` and I am not passing the `action-options` property, I get this on Dev Tools: `actionOptions: "{ columnLabel: 'Actions', }"`

Comment: It's difficult to help with the current info you provided. Is it possible you have used the child component in other places you'd missed?

Comment: Hi @hatef I found something new. If I define my prop as: 


    actionOptions: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({ columnLabel: null }),
    },


It works just fine. Now, when I replace `columnLabel` with `Actions` instead of null. The result printed is: "Actions" and not anymore an object!

Comment: I added the component inside one of the Vue views I have and all works well. Most probably it's a bug related to Storybook. This behavior happens only inside the Storybook. I will report this issue on their repo.